# Concatenate within LOOP not working as expected

Tags: php

I have a loop :

```
  $ensplit = explode("|", $elementvalues);
  $InsertAttributes = "Insert INTO NodeAttributes (Node_ID";
  foreach($ensplit as $elementname)
                 { 
                    $InsertAttributes .= ", $elementname";
                 }
```

This doesnt work. I understand why it doesn't. Only the current attribute in the loop will be added. So i will have only (Node_ID,1 element) each time. Can someone help me with a solution ?

**var_dump($ensplit) for $ensplit is something like :**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "hardware"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "access"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "IPs"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "hardware"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "access"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "IPs"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "hardware"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "access"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "IPs"
```

**print_r($ensplit)  gives :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hardware
)
Array
(
    [0] => access
)
Array
(
    [0] => IPs
)
Array
(
    [0] => hardware
)
Array
(
    [0] => access
)
Array
(
    [0] => IPs
)
Array
( ...
```

**I just copied the results via the terminal with no order.**

**var_dump($element) of $elementvalues is something like this :**

```
string(6) "access"
string(3) "IPs"
string(9) "defaultgw"
string(14) "interface_name"
string(12) "interface_rx"
string(12) "interface_tx"
string(15) "interface_error"
string(8) "hardware"
string(6) "access"
string(3) "IPs"
string(9) "defaultgw"
string(14) "interface_name"
string(12) "interface_rx"
```

**while print_r($elementvalues) is :**

`interface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardware`

**A snippet of my code output**

```
Insert INTO NodeAttributes (Node_ID, defaultgw)VALUES (10.95.8.10   , 10.95.254.165)
Insert INTO NodeAttributes (Node_ID, interface_name)VALUES (10.95.8.10  , bridge-AP-WB)
Insert INTO NodeAttributes (Node_ID, interface_rx)VALUES (10.95.8.10    , 305796188)
Insert INTO NodeAttributes (Node_ID, interface_tx)VALUES (10.95.8.10    , 2724819166)
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `$ensplit`

Comment: Do a `print_r($ensplit)` to see first if it contains what you expect. Your core seems to be correct, so I guess the problem come from `$ensplit` or `$elementvalues` vars.

Comment: This works fine for me http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yfi-cpt  Assuming, $elementvalues is a | separeted string.

Comment: Sorry I meant `$elementvalues` but yes, works fine for me as well http://codepad.org/BF5OFtZp

Comment: @RaphaëlMalié hi, i just updated the question :)

Comment: @Deryck the values have been added :)

Comment: @user3066913 do this then:  `foreach($ensplit as $element => $name) { $InsertAttributes .= ", $name"; }`

Comment: You're using `|` as the delimiter for your call to `explode`, but I don't see any `|` in your `$elementvalues` string.  Why is that?  The result of `explode` which just be an array with a single element - the entire string itself.

Comment: @AlvinLee i thought pipe with explode is just to split and make it an array not add a physical delimiter to the data ?

Comment: @Deryck sorry :( still the loop seems to override the variable each time.

Comment: @Deryck i will add my result in a sec.

Comment: @user3066913 You need to tell `explode` *how* to explode your string.  When you say that you want to split it, how will it know *where* to split it?

Comment: @AlvinLee you are right,i just noticed the mistake now ! was really blind.How may you suggest i split ? I don't see space between the words, they look joined in the print statement. ANy idea how i could split them up ?

Comment: @user3066913 I just updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've provided for `$elementvalues`, I'm inclined to think that you are not using `explode` correctly.  `explode` takes two arguments:

1. A string which acts as a delimiter, so that `explode` knows *where* to make its splits.  You have chosen `|` as your delimiter.
2. The string to explode.

The function then returns an array of all the string elements as a result of that split.

However, in examining your `$elementvalues` string, I don't see any `|` within the string.  So, `explode` would just return you an array with 1 element - the original string itself.

Documentation on how to use `explode` can be [found here](https://www.php.net/explode).

Also, another strange thing that we're seeing from your `var_dump` is that `$ensplit` is a two-dimensional array, when we would have expected a one-dimensional array.  I suspect there's something funky about your `$elementvalues` string.

*Edit - Added in response to OP's comments*

You asked (in your comment) what you should do if there is no `|` to act as a delimiter in your string.  You ask, *" I don't see space between the words, they look joined in the print statement. ANy idea how i could split them up "*

But, how would `explode` know how you want them split up unless you provide it with some additional information or rules or dictionary?  For example, let's say I gave you the following string:

```
alvinisnowhere
```

And I asked you to `explode` it into separate words, but I don't give you any delimiter.  Would `explode` know if you wanted

```
alvin
is
nowhere
```

Or

```
alvin
is
now
here
```

It can't know, unless you provide additional information.

Another thing you could do is provide some sort of dictionary of valid words.  And then, instead of using `explode`, you traverse `$elementvalues` one character at a time and keep checking to see if you have a string that is in your dictionary.

Below is code that may work for you (it works for me).  But, keep in mind the following **caveats**:

1. **This assumes that you have a dictionary of valid terms.**
2. **No term can be a substring within another term.**  That is, if you have both `access` and you have `accessible` in your dictionary, then we would need to adjust the algorithm to be smarter.  Since it looks like your dictionary of valid terms doesn't have this problem, I just provided you with simple and dirty code that does the job.

#### Code Demonstration

```
?php

$elementvalues = "interface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface
_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rx
interface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinter
face_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterfac
e_txinterface_errorhardware";
$dictionary = array(
  "access",
  "IPs",
  "defaultgw",
  "interface_name",
  "interface_rx",
  "interface_tx",
  "interface_error",
  "hardware",
  "access",
  "IPs",
  "defaultgw",
  "interface_name",
  "interface_rx");

$ensplit = array();
$current_string = '';

// Traverse $elementvalues one character at a time.
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($elementvalues); $i++) {
  // $current_string gets the next character appended to it.
  $current_string .= $elementvalues[$i];
  if (in_array($current_string, $dictionary)) {
    // If $current_string is in our dictionary of valid words,
    // then add it to our $ensplit array and then reset
    // $current_string back to a blank string to get ready
    // for finding the next term.
    array_push($ensplit, $current_string);
    $current_string = '';
  }
}

// Verify
print_r($ensplit);
```

Comment: if it returns just one element then why is it that in my results output. Each (string) element is printed separately ? each element per line ?

Answer (score 1):

I modified $ensplit.

```
 $ensplit = array('ele1','ele2','ele3','ele4','ele5');
 $InsertAttributes = "Insert INTO NodeAttributes (Node_ID";
 foreach($ensplit as $elementname)
             { 
                $InsertAttributes .= ", $elementname";
             }  

 echo $InsertAttributes;


 // returns: Insert INTO NodeAttributes (Node_ID, ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4, ele5
```

I think the problem lies within $ensplit. You should var_dump($ensplit) and tell us what you find.

---

**Edit:**

You are exploding $elementvalues with "|", but your print_r($elementvalues) returns this:

```
    interface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPshardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardwareaccessIPsinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_errorhardware
```

Which has no "|"s. How does that work?

Answer (score -2):

*EDIT: learned something new. This answer is not valid any more.*

you need to remove the `"` around the variable. Now you are parsing it as a string.

```
  $ensplit = explode("|", $elementvalues);
  $InsertAttributes = "Insert INTO NodeAttributes (Node_ID";
  foreach($ensplit as $elementname)
                 { 
                    $InsertAttributes .= ", ".$elementname;
                 }
```

Comment: PHP will handle a variable inside " " just fine

Comment: yes indeed, just tested it. didn't know that, in fact I never tried it before.

Comment: Delete your answer so you  keep your rep.